# Retreive intent extras

Tags: java, android-studio

I use an intent in my project, but it seems i don't know how to use it.

Here is my "settings" activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

i.putExtra("double", seekbar.getProgress());
startActivity(i);
```

And here my "main" activity:

```
String double_places;
Intent intent = getIntent();
double_places = intent.getStringExtra("double");

TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(double_places);
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: It's probably because seekbar.getProgress() returns an int and you're using getStringExtra in your main activity

Comment: Just replace `getStringExtra` with `Integer.toString(getIntExtra("double")`

Comment: could you past the logs from Android Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String double_places = getIntent().getStringExtra("double");

TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(double_places);
```